# Permissão de root para alterar data e hora

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Gostaria de saber como faço para o meu script ter permissão para alterar data e hora do sistema sem pedir para digitar a senha do root?

Comment: Só de curiosidade, que vantagem teria alguém colocar uma hora errada no sistema? Pq se quiser a certa, pode usar NTP, não? É coisa offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que editar o arquivo `/etc/sudoers` adicionando:

> [usuário] ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh

Comment: Isso é meio perigoso se o usuário puder editar o script, não? Melhor seria permitir apenas a alteração de hora.

Comment: Sim, mas a própria proposta da pergunta já é insegura

Comment: Insegura em que sentido? Claro que deixar mexer na hora já é um erro conceitual, mas não significa que precisa permitir tudo né?

Comment: Eu acho que não se pode deduzir dessa forma, só porque a pergunta "parece" sugerir algo perigoso, você vai sugerir uma solução perigosa? De qualquer forma, adicionar o alerta a respeito dos riscos do comando é sempre fundamental.

Comment: Em vez de dar permissão pra executar o script como SU, seria melhor dar permissão pra executar o `date`. e mesmo assim, ter certeza que o usuário não tem permissão de alterar o date. (na verdade tem outros cuidados a tomar, mas ja é melhor do que dar permissão pro script todo rodar como SU) - de qq forma acho importante sempre que o assunto for segurança, explicar na resposta os riscos envolvidos